# VB.NET string path be cut off automatically

Tags: vb.net, path

I ended up a simple program sending and receiving a RS-232 message. My parameters (baudrate, COM port) are stored in an INI file (the file will be created automatically if not existing). The progam runs without error but I don't know why it cuts off the path that point to INI file when the path length exceed a limit (there are Unicode Japanese characters in the path string)

My path string in New function (construction) is like this: `"D:\通信プログラム20120709\新しいフォルダー\新しいフォルダー\新しいフォルダー\新しいフォルダー\Debug\Config.ini"`

and in an event function, it will become: `D:\通信プログラム20120709\新しいフォルダー\新しいフォルダー\新しいフォ・`

After consulting some source on Internet, they show me that a .NET String would have a very huge capacity so I guess my problem not concerned to VB.NET String.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

**From Comments**

I found that the path is changed after the first line of code below

```
RS232TransPort = IniRoutine.GetString(IniSectionName, ConfigName.COMPort, "COM3")
RS232Baudrate = IniRoutine.GetInteger(IniSectionName, ConfigName.Baudrate, 9600)
```

This is the function to get a string:

```
Public Function GetString(ByVal Section As String, ByVal Key As String, ByVal [Default] As String) As String 

    Dim intCharCount As Integer 
    Dim objResult As New System.Text.StringBuilder(256) 

    intCharCount = GetPrivateProfileString(Section, Key, [Default], objResult, objResult.Capacity, strFilename) 
    GetString = String.Empty 

    If intCharCount > 0 Then GetString = Left(objResult.ToString, intCharCount) 

End Function
```

where strFilename is a local variable of this class.

And this is the API declaire:

```
Private Declare Ansi Function GetPrivateProfileString _ 
        Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "GetPrivateProfileStringA" _ 
        (ByVal lpApplicationName As String, _ 
        ByVal lpKeyName As String, ByVal lpDefault As String, _ 
        ByVal lpReturnedString As System.Text.StringBuilder, _ 
        ByVal nSize As Integer, ByVal lpFileName As String) _ 
        As Integer
```

Comment: Could you post the code that loads the INI file?

Comment: Also, are you using GetPrivateProfileStringW() (not GetPrivateProfileStringA)?

Comment: I found that the path is changed after the first line of code below `RS232TransPort = IniRoutine.GetString(IniSectionName, ConfigName.COMPort, "COM3")RS232Baudrate = IniRoutine.GetInteger(IniSectionName, ConfigName.Baudrate, 9600)`

Comment: Your IniRoutine class looks like it is a wrapper around GetPrivateProfileString. Are you able to post the code for IniRoutine?

Comment: This is the function to get a string: `Public Function GetString(ByVal Section As String, ByVal Key As String, ByVal [Default] As String) As String
  Dim intCharCount As Integer
  Dim objResult As New System.Text.StringBuilder(256)
  intCharCount = GetPrivateProfileString(Section, Key, _
  [Default], objResult, objResult.Capacity, strFilename)
  GetString = String.Empty
  If intCharCount > 0 Then GetString = _
     Left(objResult.ToString, intCharCount)
 End Function` where strFilename is a local variable of this class

Comment: And this is the API declaire: `Private Declare Ansi Function GetPrivateProfileString _
   Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "GetPrivateProfileStringA" _
   (ByVal lpApplicationName As String, _
   ByVal lpKeyName As String, ByVal lpDefault As String, _
   ByVal lpReturnedString As System.Text.StringBuilder, _
   ByVal nSize As Integer, ByVal lpFileName As String) _
   As Integer`

Comment: please put your code in your question, it is a **lot** easier to read.

Comment: Are you exceeding the limit for a path name?  Have you tried placing your ini files in a folder with a short path name.

Comment: Is it your intention to set a max length of your settings in the `GetString` method?  The stringbuilder you are using has a hardcoded capacity of 256 characters.

Comment: Is there a specific requirement that your configuration information come from an INI file rather than, say, the registry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using GetPrivateProfileStringA instead of GetPrivateProfileStringW.

Since you are using Unicode, you need to use GetPrivateProfileStringW instead.